# Post Swift 3 migration: How to find a crash that doesn't appear to be in my code, and xcode is not providing a crash error for

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I started updating an old app from swift 2.2 to swift 3, after a day of fixing the multitude of errors, I have come across a crash that only happens on one screen of my app, but I'm having difficulty debugging it due to a few problems.

1. Xcode is not providing a crash log for it. i.e. "Terminating app due to ..." As a matter of fact, there's literally no information given if I allow the app to run through the crash naturally. (More on that in a moment.) It just stops running, with a breakpoint added on my AppDelegate class declaration line. It does say EXC_BAD_ACCESS as a tool tip on this line, however this alone doesn't give me enough to go on to resolve the issue.
2. The crash is happening outside my code. I set a breakpoint to try to see if I had some data in a bad state or something, and not only did I not have any errant data, but long before I reached the crash, it dropped into raw instructions that I was stepping through.

Interestingly though, when I walk through the debugger until it crashes, I get some log output that I don't when it just crashes normally:

2017-04-04 13:44:32.669302-0700 deloreanMkII[2140:76007] [Common] _BSMachError: port 2207; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"

2017-04-04 13:44:32.669741-0700 deloreanMkII[2140:76007] [Common] _BSMachError: port 2207; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"

I have googled on this, and found a few things that seem related - changing the orientation settings, language settings, and a few other items. I tried all of the ones I feasibly could, and nothing fixed the issue.

Now I am at a total loss how to proceed on this issue, and I want to know how to move forward fixing this.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I thought I was clear that it does stop on exceptions. The crash line is clearly not where it's actually finding a problem. It's stopping execution on the class declaration line of my app delegate.

Comment: That is the line it will typically stop on  if you don't have an exception breakpoint. An exc_bad_access is usually "something was nil"

Comment: Yep, I am well aware - but it appear to be something in my code. And therein lies my problem. Clearly, I can't push a swift 3 update if it doesn't run - and since it's not actually giving me *any* (useful) information about the crash, I was hoping people could give me some advice about how to proceed based on the fact that the normal methods we use to gather information about a crash are unavailable to me.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Having similar issue with cannot COPY_SEND